# Django: Easy Way to Enable Translation in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, django, translation, django-i18n

Django developers might at some point run into the problem how to get translation into their JavaScript files.

Django offers a [JavaScriptCatalog](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/translation/#internationalization-in-javascript-code). It passes the translations into JavaScript, so you can call gettext, etc., from within JavaScript.

In my mind, this generates too much overload for most smaller projects. So I would like to share my solution, how to generate a lightweight translated JavaScript translated catalog.

Answer (score 1):

1. I just add a view, which generates simply a catalog of translated strings:

```py
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _


def jsi18n(request):
    """Returns a translated JavaScript catalog to access in JavaScript files"""
    translations = {
        'hello': _('Hello'),
        'world': _('World'),
        # add more translations here
    }
    return HttpResponse(
        'var my_i18n = {%s}' % ','.join("'%s':'%s'" % (key, translation) for key, translation in translations.items()),
        content_type="application/javascript"
    )
```

2. Add the view to your urlpatterns:

```py
from . import views
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('jsi18n/', views.jsi18n, name='jsi18n'),
]
```

3. Include the translation catalog prior to your JavaScript files which requires translations:

```html
{% load static %}
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% url 'jsi18n' %}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/main.js' %}"></script>
</head>
```

Now you can access your translation catalog `my_i18n` in your JavaScript file:

```js
console.log(my_i18n['hello'] + ' ' + my_i18n['world']);
```

Comment: Can you call the var `_`? So you could do `_['hello']`?

Comment: @dirkgroten No, you just get a catalog of translated strings: `var my_i18n = {'hello':'Hello','world':'World'}`. If you want to call gettext, etc. in your JavaScript code, you have to use the django JavaScriptCatalog.

Comment: I understand what you're doing. I'm suggesting to call the var _ instead of my_i18n. `my_i18n['hello']` is ugly in js code.

Comment: For sure you can rename the catalog to anything you want. But I'm not sure if `_` violates any naming conventions in JavaScript.

Comment: That's why I asked if you tried it. It would be cool to be able to use _

Comment: It would be faster to just inject the translations into the base.html template that loads the initial .js. However, you are forgetting that the translation library handles formatting, dates, plurals, etc. You solution works if the use case is simplistic